# Get name of branch passed to git merge

Tags: python, git, merge, githooks

I am writing a prepare-commit-msg (as a pre-merge) hook and need to get the source branch name of a merge to pass to a REST API. In other words I need to get the value of branchname from `git merge <branchname>.`

So far, I've tried to rev-parse MERGE_HEAD, but it appears it has not been set yet when the hook triggers. At the moment, I'm just using git revparse --abbrev-ref @{-1} to get the last branch I was on, but that's not necessarily going to always be the branch I want to merge.

The rule I'm trying to enforce is that users should not be able to merge their feature branch with master unless certain conditions have been met. If there's a better hook to do this with then that would help too. Prepare-commit-msg is the only one that seems to have the commit type as an argument.

Comment: I'm not sure it's even possible in `git` because `prepare-commit-msg` hook is *not* even run on `fast-forward` merges.

Comment: right. I've turned off fast-forward merges for everything but pulls. I wish they'd just add a pre-merge hook already :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So far, I've tried to rev-parse MERGE_HEAD, but it appears it has not been set yet when the hook triggers.

That's correct; but the problem is bigger than that.  (And/or smaller, perhaps! :-) )  (I'll note [Arkadiusz Drabczyk's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43686807/get-name-of-branch-passed-to-git-merge/43687614#comment74421081_43686807) here too: a `git merge` that does no merging—i.e., one that fast-forwards—skips *everything*.)

First, consider what happens if a user runs:

```
git merge a97131c
```

What *branch* is this merging?  Well, let's draw a bit of the graph:

```
...--*--o--o--@   <-- blarg (HEAD), xtest
      \
       o--A--B   <-- br1
           \
            C   <-- br2, br3
```

`HEAD` tells us that the current branch's name is `blarg`, so although the current commit is commit `@` (whose hash is perhaps `9fd178a`, for instance), once the merge commit is actually made, it is the name `blarg` that will point to the new merge commit.

Next, which commit is `a97131c`?  It might be any of commits `A`, `B`, and `C`.  If it's commit `A`, this is not itself any branch tip, so there is *no* appropriate name for the branch being merged.  We're just merging commit `A` so that the result will be:

```
...--*--o--o--o   <-- xtest
      \        \
       o-----A--@   <-- blarg (HEAD)
             |\
             | B  <-- br1
              \
               C   <-- br2, br3
```

If `a97131c` is the ID of commit `B`, we're probably doing `git merge br1`, so the result will be:

```
...--*--o--o--o   <-- xtest
      \        \
       o        @  <-- blarg (HEAD)
        \      /
         A----B   <-- br1
          \
           C   <-- br2, br3
```

If `a97131c` is the ID of commit `C`, we're probably doing either `git merge br2` or `git merge br3`.  (I'll leave drawing the resulting graph as an exercise, but note that as before, the only *name* that moves is `blarg`.)

Anyway, this is a long-winded way to say that even if you can get the *name* of the branch someone issued as an argument—and often, you can: it's secreted away in `.git/MERGE_MSG`—it's not actually important.  *In Git, branch names almost don't matter.*  What matters are commits.

#### So what *can* you do?

> The rule I'm trying to enforce is that users should not be able to merge their feature branch with master unless certain conditions have been met. If there's a better hook to do this with then that would help too. Prepare-commit-msg is the only one that seems to have the commit type as an argument.

It sounds as though the real goal is to prohibit commits that result in *any* new commit or commits appearing on `master` unless those new commits meet some constraint(s).  I do not know what your constraints are, of course, and I can only note several more items:

- `git merge` skips the regular `pre-commit` and `commit-msg` hooks entirely whenever the merge goes well automatically.  So you would have to use the `prepare-commit-msg` hook to catch this very early.
- However, if a `prepare-commit-msg` hook exits nonzero during a `git merge`, the merge is still in progress.  A subsequent `git commit` will commit the merge.  This operation *does* run the `pre-commit` and `commit-msg` hooks (unlike a successful automatic merge).  Again, however, while exiting nonzero prevents the commit, the merge is still in progress, ready to be committed.
- Users can always skip these hooks (or not set them up).  To truly enforce something, you need to do this at the point the commit enters some repository *you* control.  In many typical setups, this means in a centralized repository to which individual developers `git push` their work.  You would do this enforcing in a `pre-receive` or `update` hook (and/or via Gitolite and its fancier systems).

All that said, it might still be nice to enforce some rules at the individual developer end, so that they don't do a lot of work and think all is good and then go to push and have the push fail.  The simplest way to handle *this* is to write a wrapper that someone is to use: instead of directly running `git checkout master; git merge featureX`, they run your wrapper, which does the pre-checks and then only even bothers *invoking* `git merge` if things look OK.

You can still implement strict enforcement on the centralized server, to make sure developers have not bypassed the rules.  But you give them a tool to help them out, and say: "If you want to avoid stumbling over the rules very late, use this tool."

Comment: That, @torek, is a beautiful response! Thank you for taking the time to do all this. That answers my question. I think I'm going to go the wrapper route. I think that's a good short-term solution. In the long run, I think I'll go for the server-side hooks. We're using Bitbucket server though and getting their plugin sdk onto our isolated network is a bit of a pain...bureaucracy and all that jazz...Thanks again for the help!